# How do you display values from a table based on another table in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 Models a customer table and a product table.  I am pretty new to MVC and I have created a model and I have the auto generated controller and views for details, delete, create... etc...

My models are:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

[Table("Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, how do I display a list of the products based on the customer name.  Obviously they are joined by CustomerId but how do I combine controllers.  So I want to display some data based on data from another table.

Comment: You might want to look at this tutorial regarding related data in an ASP.NET MVC application: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. (I also recommend to follow the complete tutorial if you haven't done so.)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to stick to an MVC 4 tutorial which did not help me with this but this one looks good!

Comment: If you are starting with MVC, you can follow MVC 3 tutorials as they will generally work with MVC 4. And later on, you can start using the new features introduced in this last version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a Navigation Property to Customer.

```
[Table("Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use that to access the products for a customer.

```
public ActionResult ProductsByCustomer(string id)
{
    // Find the customer by name
    var customer = dbContext.Customer.First(c => c.Name == id);

    // Get the customers products
    var customersProducts = customer.Products;

    // Send products to the View to be rendered
    return View(customersProducts);
}
```