# MVC Table1 does not contain definition from Table2 but the navigation property exists

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

**Staff table**

```
[Table("Staff")]
public partial class Staff
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StaffID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AllocatedLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BalanceLeave { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CurrentApplication> CurrentApplications { get; set; }
}
```

**CurrentApplication table**

```
[Table("CurrentApplication")]
public partial class CurrentApplication
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StaffID { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string LeaveType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> NoOfDays { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> NoOfHours { get; set; }
    public string AppStatus { get; set; }
    public int HiddenID { get; set; }
    public string LeaveReason { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public Staff Staff { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
private SampleDBEntities1 db = new SampleDBEntities1();

    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var userEmail = User.Identity.Name;
        var model = db.Staffs.Where(i => i.Email == userEmail);

        var model1 = model.CurrentApplications;
        var ummm = new LeaveIndexData { Staffs = model, CurrentApplications = model1 };

        return View(ummm);
    }
```

I'm using database generated with EF. I tried following [How do you display values from a table based on another table in MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587336/how-do-you-display-values-from-a-table-based-on-another-table-in-mvc-4) because it is similar to what I want to achieve but I got the error

> Error 1   'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a
>   definition for 'CurrentApplications' and no extension method
>   'CurrentApplications' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

But the code seems correct to me ... and i have another tutorial I did and the codes are similar too but I have no idea why it doesn't work here for me. I've been trying to resolve this error for a really long time T_T If you need to look at any other parts of my program please let me know I'll edit and include it here. Thank you!

Comment: You probably meant `db.Staffs.Single(i => i.Email == userEmail)` instead. `Where()` is returning a collection (even if only single item matched).

Comment: @haim770 hi now i get the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'test.Models.Staff' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<test.Models.Staff>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). What do I have to do? :o

Comment: What is the type of `LeaveIndexData.Staffs`, and the type of `LeaveIndexData.CurrentApplications `?

Comment: Can you try to add a constructor to your `Staff` model to initialize  `CurrentApplications` ? Like this: `public Staff() {CurrentApplications = new HashSet<CurrentApplication>(); }`